# Missing values in object in R lme

Tags: r, model, nlme

I am working on a simple model in R:

```
fit<-lme(x~y, data, random=~1|subject)
```

But I keep getting this error:

> Error in na.fail.default(list(h1 = c(103L, 20L, 34L, 85L, 47L, 136L,
>   76L,  :    missing values in object

(h1 is one of my column titles of a factor)

Any idea on how to fix this? An identical model works with a different set of data.

Comment: The error suggests you have missing values in the data, You either need to omit data with missing values or Impute missing values

Comment: Take a look at the help page for `lme`, specifically at the `na.action` argument.  The default is set to `na.fail`.  You might want to choose a different option.

Comment: This question will basically be unanswerable unless you can please include data and/or code that will provide us with a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) ?  (Especially since you say that the same model works with a different set of data ...)  Otherwise I'm going to vote to close as "unclear what you're asking" ...

Answer (score 15):

Set `na.action` equal to `na.omit` in your function call:

```
fit<-lme(x~y, data, random=~1|subject, na.action=na.omit)
```

`nlme` defaults to `na.fail` when `NA`s are found. This is not the case with `lme4::lmer()` where `na.action` is equal to `na.omit` by default.

Edit: oops, after replying I noticed this is an old and most likely dead question.

Comment: Maybe dead, but your post helped me!